# How to deploy to aws lambda from Jfrog pipelines

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

How to deploy aws lambda SAM project using Jfrog pipelines. Does Jfrog support this?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can use the aws integration and then do everything via the aws cli